# TypeError: Cannot read property 'videos' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am using `yt-search` module for searching YouTube content and here is some code that I use:

```
const yts = require("yt-search")
await yts( "yorushika", function ( err, r ) {
     console.log(r.videos.length)
}
```

And this produces the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'videos' of undefined
    at /root/pkb/commands/music/play.js:19:27
    at l (/root/pkb/node_modules/yt-search/dist/yt-search.min.js:1:1287)
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/yt-search/dist/yt-search.min.js:1:6750
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/async.util.parallel/index.js:20:9
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/async.util.once/index.js:6:12
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/async.util.eachoflimit/index.js:36:25
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/async.util.onlyonce/index.js:6:12
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/async.util.parallel/index.js:17:13
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/async.util.restparam/index.js:14:29
    at /root/pkb/node_modules/yt-search/dist/yt-search.min.js:1:6669
```

r is

```
{
  videos: [
    {
      type: 'video',
      title: 'ヨルシカ - 夜行 (OFFICIAL VIDEO)',
      description: 'ヨルシカ - 夜行Yorushika - Night Journey作詞作曲、編曲(Words and Music): n-bunaVocal: suis Official Sitehttp://yorushika ...',
      url: 'https://youtube.com/watch?v=MH5noJJfqDY',
      videoId: 'MH5noJJfqDY',
      seconds: 219,
      timestamp: '3:39',
      duration: [Object],
      views: 949413,
      thumbnail: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MH5noJJfqDY/default.jpg',
      image: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MH5noJJfqDY/hqdefault.jpg',
      ago: '2 days ago',
      author: [Object]
    },
    {
      type: 'video',
      title: 'ヨルシカ - 言って。(Music Video)',
      description: 'ヨルシカ 「言って。」Yorushika - Say it作詞、作曲、編曲：n-bunaVocal：suisMusic Video Directed by 大鳥http://yorushika.com/ヨル ...',
      url: 'https://youtube.com/watch?v=F64yFFnZfkI',
      videoId: 'F64yFFnZfkI',
      seconds: 244,
      timestamp: '4:04',
      duration: [Object],
      views: 57577275,
    //and more
}
```

I want to fix the error but don't know how (One day ago, `npm install yt-search@latest` solved it, but today it does not work).

Comment: Might be an idea to check `err`..

Comment: Try to add `if ( err ) throw err` before `console.log(r.videos.length)`. What error message are you getting now?

Comment: The code you presented seems to work correctly. As it has been pointed out, maybe you are getting an error instead of the videos data?